# Suppose that a planar graph has $k$ connected components, $e$ edges, and $v$ vertices. Also suppose that$\dots$

Tags: graph-theory

**Question:**
Suppose that a planar graph has $k$ connected components, $e$ edges, and $v$ vertices. Also suppose that the plane is divided into $r$ regions by a planar representation of the graph. Find a formula for $r$ in terms of $e, v,$ and $k$.

**Attempt:**
Let $r_i, v_i, e_i$ be the number of regions, edges, vertices in the $i^{th}$ connected component, thus

$$r_i = e_i - v_i + 2$$

Suppose we ignore the outer most regions for now, our new equation is,

$$r_i' = e_i - v_i + 2 - 1$$
$$= r_i' = e_i - v_i + 1$$

Adding them all, we get,

where $r_1' + r_2' + \dots r_k' = r''$; $e_1 + e_2 + \dots e_k = e$; $v_1 + v_2 + \dots v_k = v$, therefore

$$r_1' + r_2' + \dots + r_k' = \\r'' = e-v+k$$

Since $r''$ is deprived of any outer regions, we add one to reintroduce the outer region, thus $r = r'' + 1$,

$$r = e-v+k+1$$

> Is that attempt correct? It seems too ad-hoc for me (I've never done
>   or seen this pattern of solving problem before).

Comment: Looks good to me. Your proof is an actual hidden induction by $k$, after you found the right formula, it might be easier to prove it directly by induction.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain how you got the first expression for $r_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems valid to me. This is exactly the approach I was going to take.

Comment: Sorry, from where does it follow the first expression for $r_i$ in his proof?

Comment: see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler's_formula